# Dataframes: Modify entire column based on corresponding row in another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe, `my_df`:

```
>>> my_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col_1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 'col_2': [100, 2, 300, 4, 500], 'unused_col': [1, 1, 1, 1, 900]})
>>> my_df
   col_1  col_2  unused_col
0     10    100           1
1     20      2           1
2     30    300           1
3     40      4           1
4     50    500         900
```

If the value in col_2 is greater than the value in col_1, I want to set the value in col_1 to the value in col_2. Otherwise, leave it as is. So, the desired output is:

```
   col_1  col_2  unused_col
0    100    100           1
1     20      2           1
2    300    300           1
3     40      4           1
4    500    500         900
```

How do I accomplish this, without modifying the values in unused_col?

Comment: `df['col_1'] = df.max(axis=1)`

Comment: if there are columns else `df['col_1'] = df[['col_1','col_2']].max(axis=1)`

Comment: There are other columns - I updated my question.
Also, why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: *why is this getting downvoted*  - i don't know. Perhaps, all know the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `np.where()`:

```
import numpy as np    
df['col_1'] = np.where(df['col_2'] > df['col_1'], df['col_2'],df['col_1'])
```

This reads as: "col_1 is equal to: if the row for col_2 is larger than the one for col_1 then return col_2, otherwise return col_1". This will be applied for each row individually, of course.